# NUnit Assert event .Any suggestions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Wondering if this is the correct way to test result with events.

I am working on a application that when Save is in progress/completed it fires events.

In order to test it I have come up with the following (Made up scenario). And I'm wondering if this is the way you do it:

```
[Test]
public void Save_WhenCalled_IsSuccessfull()
{
    //Arrange
    var customerService= new CustomerService();

    customerService.OnSaved += (sender, args) =>
        {                                             
            Assert.IsTrue(args.HasSaved);
        };

    customerService.Save(new Customer {Id=1,Name="Jo"});
}
```

What I dont like is that I am asserting before if you see what I mean.

I would like the assert to be visually last. By the way the above works just fine, but not quite happy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into this ? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248989/unit-testing-that-an-event-is-raised-in-c-sharp

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov seen now,I see that the difference is that he creates a list and adds all the events there, and then he queries the list in the assert.Is that correct?.Should I create a dictionary EG PropertyName,Value and then query it? is that a better way to do it

Comment: @user231465, according to the name of your test method, that would not be necessary in this case. It helps to keep the test as simple as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks good, but you should store the received parameters (or any other check) in a variable in order to keep the arrange/act/assert sequence. That way you also assert that the event has actually fired, something your example does not verify.

```
[Test]
public void Save_WhenCalled_IsSuccessfull()
{
    //Arrange
    YourArgsType actualArgs;
    var customerService= new CustomerService();  
    customerService.OnSaved+= (sender, args) =>
                                  {                                           
                                      actualArgs = args;
                                  };

    //Act
    customerService.Save(new Customer{Id=1, Name="Jo"});

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(actualArgs.HasSaved);
}
```

**EDIT:** Added Alexander suggestion.

Comment: wow,That is exactly what I was after!! why didnt i think of that :)

Comment: Another significant improvement here is that now test fails when `OnSaved` event is not fired. The example which is provided in question does not consider that.