# How to test a method with TokenSource cancellation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xunit, cancellationtokensource

I have a problems with unit testing of a method with TokenSource cancellation.

SUT method is very simple:

```
public void OnTaskCancellationExecute(object obj)
        {
            TaskCancellation = true;

            TokenSource.Cancel();

            CommandCompletedControlsSetup();
        }
```

And is called by command execution:

`TaskCancellationCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnTaskCancellationExecute);`

`CommandCompletedControlsSetup` method, that is executed after `TokenSource` is cancelled, contains:

`TaskCancellation = false;`

My test method:

```
[Fact]
    public void OnTaskCancellationExecute_CancelTask_True()
    {
        _viewModel.TaskCancellation = false;
        _viewModel.TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _viewModel.TaskCancellationCommand.Execute(null);

        Assert.True(_viewModel.TaskCancellation);
    }
```

Cancellation of all Tasks with `TokenSource` in SUT takes a while in running solution. But not in unit testing. How should I `Assert`, that `_viewModel.TaskCancellation` was `true`, before was changed again to `false` after `CommandCompletedControlsSetup` was called in tested method? Or it is kind of problem with my architecture? Should I create some Tasks in test method and attach the SUT tokens somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way it is not possible. Since you set `TaskCancellation` *explicitly* to `true` right after entering the method you don't need to test the property itself. It will work of course. If the value of `TaskCancellation` is the result of an operation you would test this operation separately. If the value of `TaskCancellation` is the result of a condition you would test this condition separately. To test your example code, you first assert that the `TokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` is `true` after the command has executed. Then write a second test case to test `CommandCompletedControlsSetup()`.

Comment: Yeah, I started to consider similar scenario. I could also try to count property events like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248989/unit-testing-that-an-event-is-raised-in-c-sharp . But it might not have a sence. Thank you for reply!

Comment: You could. But to me in case of a property this doesn't make sense. You would effectively test the property or the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface itself. This is useless. If it was `TaskCancellation = IsValid()` you would test `IsValid()`. If it was `TaskCancellation = this.value > 100 && this.result.IsSuccesful` you would test this condition and assert that `TaskCancellation` matches the expected result. But as a precondition (because `CommandCompletedControlsSetup()´ is executed at the end).