# How to test that an event will not be fired in xUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, xunit

I have two questions.

1. Does it make sense to test that an event will not be fired?
2. If yes, what is the best way to accomplish that using the `xUnit` framework?

For example, I have a class with a single property `Mark`,

```
public class Box : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Marking mark = Marking.None;

  public Marking Mark
  {
    get
    {
      return mark;
    }
    set
    {
      mark = value;
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Mark)));
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and *I want to test* that when someone is going to set the value of `Mark` to the same value as the property points currently, then the `PropertyChanged` event will not be fired.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit testing that events are raised in C# (in order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248989/unit-testing-that-events-are-raised-in-c-sharp-in-order)

Comment: Nope @PavelAnikhouski, all good I've got an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, it makes perfect sense. If the requirement is that an event should not be fired under certain circumstances, then there should be a test for it.

2) Something like this:
‍‍

```
[Fact]
public void PropertyChangedNotFired()
{
    Box box = new Box();

    int fireCount = 0;

    box.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => ++fireCount;

    box.Mark = Marking.Tick;

    Assert.Equal(1, fireCount); // Sanity check. Not strictly speaking following AAA

    box.Mark = Marking.Tick;

    Assert.Equal(1, fireCount); // If we get 2, event has wrongly fired
}
```

This assumes an enum (which you didn't show) something like:

```
public enum Marking { None, Tick, Cross }
```

Comment: Thanks, so I need to implement my own logic, I mean there's nothing like `Assert.NotRaised` for example.

Comment: That's my enum, from what it seems it didn't had to be shown :)

Comment: I don't think there's anything like `Assert.NotRasied` in any testing framework. Maybe in a mocking framework.

Comment: @Themelis You mean that's your `enum` exactly? I'm psychic.

Comment: That's exactly my enum @Jasper!