# How to raise event in MSTest?

Tags: c#, events, tdd, mstest, nsubstitute

I am writing a test to see if my class reacts correctly to an event (and mind you, I just started TDD, so bear with me).

The class I want to test against registers an event handler:

```
class MyClass {
       public MyClass(INotifyPropertyChanged propertyChanged) {
            propertyChanged.PropertyChanged += MyHandler;
       }
}
```

and my test looks something like this (this is where I am stuck):

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyClass_ShouldHandleEventCorrectly() {
    // Arrange
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    // Act (this obviously doesn't work ....)
    myClass.PropertyChanged.Invoke()

    // Assert
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit testing that events are raised in C# (in order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248989/unit-testing-that-events-are-raised-in-c-sharp-in-order)

Comment: What do you want to test exactly. As this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi I have that a lot, when writing tests :). I want to test if my `myClass` handles a certain event correctly.

Comment: @Peska no. That explains how to 'catch' events, not raise them. I want to raise an event in my class under test and check if the results are correct. I found the answer already though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken in who should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Turns out not the event receiver should implement it, but the event sender. Not wanting to instantiate that (because then I would test two classes in the same test, which I think is not what you want), I used `NSubstitute` to mock it and [their documentation](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/raising-events/) showed me how to raise the event:

```
// Arrange
INotifyPropertyChanged notifyPropertyChanged = Substitute.For<INotifyPropertyChanged>();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(notifyPropertyChanged);

// Act
notifyPropertyChanged += Raise.Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler>(notifyPropertyChanged, new PropertyChangedEventHandlerArgs("property"));

// Assert
... check whatever needed in myClass
```